# Google maps spiderfy function - more than one marker at the same point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to use the Overlapping Marker Spiderfier for Google Maps API v3 found here. (my questions are at the bottom of this block of text/code)

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/blob/master/README.textile

The page I'm trying to implement it on is a bit different than the code they use on their source code page. They initialize their page and implement all of their function calls within the initialization function. My page initializes the map and loads one point, and then additional points are added later using a separate function (through geocoding).

So, essentially at this point the map has been initialized, now I call my database to get new locations to add.

```
var cityArray= <?php echo json_encode($cityArray); ?>; //get the city
var title = <?php echo json_encode($title); ?>; //and the title to go on it's infowindow

  function plotMarkers(){ 
        for(var i = 0; i < <?php echo json_encode($length); ?>; i++){
            codeAddresses(cityArray[i],title[i]); //geocode the address
        }
  }
```

So, this snippet above gives me two arrays; one with a location, and one with the title to go in the info window. The

So, now here's the codeAddresses function that geocodes the address, and adds that marker to the map. As you can see from the plotMarkers function, the arrays are looped through and added to the codeAddresses funciton.

```
function codeAddresses(address,title){
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) { 
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 position: results[0].geometry.location
                });      
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
              return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(title);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
              }
            })(marker));
        }
    });
  }
```

My question is do I add the listeners (on the page linked above) to my first function that loads the first point, or should I add it to the codeAddresses function?

Also, should I include this in my codeAddresses function or somewhere else? If it does go in codeAddresses, does that mean I can get rid of the for loop because codeAddresses is triggered from a loop (and gets run during each iteration)?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < window.mapData.length; i ++) {
   var datum = window.mapData[i];
   var loc = new gm.LatLng(datum.lat, datum.lon);
   var marker = new gm.Marker({
   position: loc,
   title: datum.h,
   map: map
});
 marker.desc = datum.d;
 oms.addMarker(marker);  // <-- here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best [strategy](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) is to geocode the addresses offline (using the [geocoding web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)), store the coordinates in your database, then use them to display the markers, this will reduce the time to load your page since the geocoder is subject to rate limits and quotas.

Comment: I'd still have to use a function to plot these points (that i'm looking up from the database), correct? Could I still use the spiderfy function with this? I'm having trouble showing overlapping points to display and this seems to be better than clustering.

Comment: Yes. But storing the coordinates in your database reduces the time to display (your user doesn't need to wait for the geocoder to return results) and is more reliable (the geocoder sometimes doesn't return the result desired, if you store the coordinates in your database, you can correct them).  Here is an [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) that plots coordinates from xml, [here is another](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html) that uses the MarkerClusterer (you can pretty much replace the MarkerClusterer with the spiderifier.

Comment: Any chance you could provide some example code of using a markerclusterer (as far as getting the points into XML)? I didn't have much luck getting this to work, so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I provided [a live example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html) in my last comment.  Unless you are asking about how to generate the xml, in which case look at [the articles section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/) for examples using PHP and MySQL.